# I don't have headers on my screens but i want to have header only on one screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I use [reactnavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) for navigation. I don't have headers on my screens but i want to have header only on one screen (especially back button). 
This is my root navigator:

```
...
class RootNavigation extends Component {
  props: Props;

  render() {
    const { isProfileSelect } = this.props;
    const initialRouteName = currentRoute(isProfileSelect);

    const RootStackNav = StackNavigator(
      {
        AppHome: { screen: TabBarNavigator },
        SwitchProfile: { screen: SwitchProfileScreen },
        Pin: { screen: PinScreen },
      },
      {
        initialRouteName,
        headerMode: 'none',
      },
    );

    return <RootStackNav />;
  }
}
...
```

there is `headerMode: 'none',` it does mean i haven't any header navigator it is good for screens `AppHome`,`SwitchProfile` but not for `Pin` i need back button on header. Because I have to go on `SwitchScreen` and there i can continue on `Pin` screen and from `Pin` screen i sometime need go back to `SwitchScreen` And i have no back button on IOS. I need set header only in pin screen.

this is `navigationOptions` for pin screen:

```
...
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: I18n.t('screens.pinScreen.navigationOptions.title'),
  };
...
```

but changes haven't any effect

Can you help me to add header only on `Pin` screen?
Thank you

**update:**
***SOLUTION***

```
const RootStackNav = StackNavigator(
  {
    AppHome: {
      screen: TabBarNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Header title',
        headerMode: 'screen',
        header: null,
      },
     },
    SwitchProfile: {
      screen: SwitchProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Header title',
        headerMode: 'screen',
        header: null,
      },
    },
    Pin: {
      screen: PinScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Header title',
        headerMode: 'screen',
        // header: null,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName,
    // headerMode: 'none',
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My case was reverse of yours...
I wanted to disable the header on one screen so I added the following code in that particular screen.

```
export default class NoHeaderView extends Component {
static navigationOptions = { header: null }
...
//your constructor, render and other stuff
...
}//
```

Let me know if it works.